# Validate DATE format in Python Pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have the following pandas dataFrame, and I am trying to validate all the data from that DATE_DELIVERY column that needs to be in format MM/DD/YYYY before proceeding with the program:

```
rowNum = 0
    
for dateValue in dataFrame['DATE_DELIVERY']:
    try:
        rowNum += 1
        dateValue = datetime.datetime.strftime(dateValue, '%m/%d/%Y')
    except:
        print(f"%%%%%% ERROR ---> INCORRECT DATE FORMAT: {dateValue}, DATE FORMAT SHOULD BE: MM/DD/YYYY")
        sys.exit()
```

The code above gives me the OUTPUT from inside the except clause which means the try clause is failing:

```
%%%%%% ERROR ---> INCORRECT DATE FORMAT: 01/01/2022 ON ROW #2, DATE FORMAT SHOULD BE: MM/DD/YYYY
```

NOTE: The date comes from a CSV file as '01/01/2022' I am not sure what I am doing wrong, is there any other way to validate the date format?

Comment: Try with `pd.to_datetime(dataFrame['DATE_DELIVERY'].str.strip(), format='%m/%d/%Y')`. You can add `errors='coerce'` as parameter of `pd.to_datetime` and check if there are some `nan` values.

Comment: maybe pass `errors='coerce'` to `to_datetime` as well, so the invalid dates come out as `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will employ `strptime` instead of `strftime`. `strptime` parses a string and tries to convert it into a `datetime` object.

```
import datetime
import sys

rowNum = 0

for dateValue in dataFrame['DATE_DELIVERY']:
    try:
        rowNum += 1
        datetime.datetime.strptime(dateValue, '%m/%d/%Y')
    except ValueError:
        print(f"%%%%%% ERROR ---> INCORRECT DATE FORMAT: {dateValue} ON ROW #{rowNum}, DATE FORMAT SHOULD BE: MM/DD/YYYY")
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Nice point! I didn't see this error.